# Issues with grid layout when calling tkraise() in fairly simple GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am playing around with a few new ideas for a program I am writing that has five frames within the root managed by the grid layout. One of the larger frames is a container to hold multiple frames within itself, and then you can push a button to flip between them. When you push the button the first time, frame will change, but in knocks off two of the original 5 frames, leaving me with a total of 3. The only thing I could do to fix this was re defining the frames again in my switch_frame method, but I was wondering if there was another way to deal with this without having to create new objects.

```
from tkinter import *


class NewFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent: Tk):
        Frame.__init__(self, master=parent, width=parent.winfo_screenwidth() * .75
                       , height=parent.winfo_screenheight() * .8, bg="purple")
        self.switch_button = Button(self, text='back', command=lambda: parent.switch_multi(1)).pack()

    
class NewFrame2(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent: Tk):
        Frame.__init__(self, master=parent, width=parent.winfo_screenwidth() * .75
                       , height=parent.winfo_screenheight() * .8, bg="black")
        self.switch_button = Button(self, text='back', command=lambda: parent.switch_multi(0)).pack()


class Main_UI(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)

        self.title("RobinFree")
        self.iconbitmap("C:/RobinFree/pics/robinhood.ico")
        self.state("zoomed")

        # logo frame
        self.logo_frame = Frame(self, width=self.winfo_screenwidth() * .45,
                                height=self.winfo_screenheight() * .2, bg="yellow")
        self.logo_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, stick=N + E + S + W)

        # funds frame
        self.funds_frame = Frame(self, width=self.winfo_screenwidth() * .55,
                                 height=self.winfo_screenheight() * .2, bg="orange")
        self.funds_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, stick=N + E + S + W)

        # multi frame
        self.multi_frame_holder = []

        self.multi_frame_container = Frame(self, width=self.winfo_screenwidth() * .75
                                           , height=self.winfo_screenheight() * .8, bg="red")
        self.multi_frame_container.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, stick=N + E + S + W)
        self.switch_button = Button(self.multi_frame_container, text='back',
                                    command=lambda: self.switch_multi(1)).pack()

        self.second_frame = NewFrame(self)
        self.second_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, stick=N + E + S + W)
        self.multi_frame_holder.append(self.second_frame)

        self.third_frame = NewFrame2(self)
        self.third_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, stick=N + E + S + W)
        self.multi_frame_holder.append(self.third_frame)

        self.switch_multi(0)

        # positions frame
        self.positions_frame = Frame(self, width=self.winfo_screenwidth() * .25
                                     , height=self.winfo_screenheight() * .4, bg="blue")
        self.positions_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, stick=N + E + S)

        # lvl2 frame
        self.lvl2_frame = Frame(self, width=self.winfo_screenwidth() * .25
                                , height=self.winfo_screenheight() * .4, bg="green")
        self.lvl2_frame.grid(row=2, column=1, stick=N + E + S)

    def switch_multi(self, index: int):
        label = self.multi_frame_holder[index]
        label.tkraise()

x = Main_UI()
x.mainloop()
```

Comment: to clarify, you want the black and purple to switch, but the blue and green ones should be over top of the frames at all times?

Comment: Yeah, the self.lvl2_frame and self.positions_frame vanish after the big purple/black frame is switched

Comment: You are giving your widgets conflicting row/column numbers.  Your multi_frame is in rows 1 and 2, columns 0 and 1; `positions_frame` is also in the top right corner of that area, and `lvl2_frame` is in the lower right corner.  Getting rid of `columnspan=2` in the several places it appears looks like it would fix that.

Answer (score 0):

`tkraise` can take an element as argument to raise it above that element, so if you pass the other elements in the `multi_frame_holder` it will only raise above those and not raise above everything:

```
    label = self.multi_frame_holder[index]
    for i,elem in enumerate(self.multi_frame_holder):
        if i!= index:
            # raise above all other elements in multi_frame_holder but no higher.
            label.tkraise(elem)
```